# using x-editable in codeigniter not updated record DB

Tags: php, codeigniter, x-editable

I try to use x-editable in codeigniter, but value from x-editable not sent to my controller. This is my view code :

```
 <td class="numeric"><center><a href="#" class="status_order" data-type="select" 
                                data-pk="<?=$data['id_faktur'];?>" data-name="status"
                                data-title="STATUS PEMBELIAN">
                                <?=$data['status'];?></a></center>
                              </td>
```

This is my controller :

```
$pk = $this->input->post('pk');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $value = $this->input->post('value');

    $data = array (
        'status' => $value
        );
    print_r($data);die();
```

Can anybody help me, thanks before...

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and check the value for it!!

Comment: it doesn't work, hmmm

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you should define a data-url attribute i.e.

```
<td class="numeric">
    <center>
        <a href="#" class="status_order" data-url="/your_controller_url/" data-type="select" data-pk="<?=$data['id_faktur'];?>" data-name="status" data-title="STATUS PEMBELIAN"> <?=$data['status'];?></a>
    </center>
</td>
```

Source: 
[Documentation - getting started](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html)